# how to bind the data form dAtabase in c#

Tags: c#

"
             SelectCommand="select  case when len(T.hallticketno)=1 then '0000'+ convert(varchar(20),T.hallticketno)
 when len(T.hallticketno)=2 then '000'+ Convert(varchar(20),T.hallticketno)
 when len(T.hallticketno)=3  then '00'+ Convert(varchar(20),T.hallticketno)
 when len(T.hallticketno)=4  then '0'+ Convert(varchar(20),T.hallticketno)
 when len(T.hallticketno)=5  then  Convert(varchar(20),T.hallticketno)  end as Hallticketno 
,T.Studentname,(select senseiname from senseimaster where senseiid=T.senseiID) as SenseiName,(select kyuname from kyumaster where kyuid= T.kyuid) as Kyu,(select groupname from groupmaster where groupid= T.groupid) as GroupName,T.Fathername,convert(varchar(20),T.dob,103) as Dob,  case when T.sex=0 then 'Male' else 'Female' end as Gender
from applicationForm T  where Franchiseid =@FRANCHISEID and Competitionid=@competitionId
order by groupname ">
    
  --%>
    
        
        
        **CompanyName**
        
        **City**
        
        
         
         
         
         
         
             
            
             
             
          --%>

```
<table id ="sample " border ="1px" visible ="false" >    
    <tr>
    <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat ="server" Font-Bold="true" Text ='<%#Bind(CompetitionName)%>' ></asp:Label><td style="width: 100px">            
        </td>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        </td>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px">
            Venue</td>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat ="server" Font-Bold="true" Text ='<%Bind(competitionaddress) %>'  ></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
            Date of Competition</td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        <asp:Label ID ="Label15" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px">
            Hall Ticket No</td>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large"  ID="Label16" runat="server"  ></asp:Label> 
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
            Group</td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server"  Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <%--<asp:Label ID="Lable1" runat ="server" Font-Bold="true"  Text ='<%Bind("GroupName")%>'></asp:Label>--%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px">
            Student Name</td>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        <asp:Label  ID ="Lable18" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
            Kyu</td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        <asp:Label ID="Lable19" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" style="width: 100px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        <asp:Label ID ="Lable20" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
            Franchise Name</td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        <asp:Label ID ="Lable21" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
            Sensei's Name</td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        <asp:Label ID ="Lable22" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 106px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 106px">
            Signature of HO</td>
        <td style="width: 127px">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 129px">
            Signature of Student</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<%--</asp:Repeater> --%>
```

if i click the Hall Ticket then the data sholud be bound to particular field...how to do friends plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a control supporting DataBind, enclosing your table, like a FormView.

Comment: can u send me example with code friend plz dont mistake me for asking u again